# Do I have to setup VM options each time I want to run a Javafx program

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I am just trying to figure out a way to setup a javafx application without having to setup vm options everytime.

Comment: For development, use Maven or Gradle with the appropriate plugin and much of the hassle should be handled for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij Idea you can define VM options in Run/Debug configuration:

[image]

So, every time you run the application, the defined VM options will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can set VM options in the `$IDE_HOME/bin/idea64.vmoptions`